# Loading file to server

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have two forms on one page that should give users posibility to load file to server(from URL or from user's PC)

```
<form method="post" action="bigorder.php" name="photourl">
  <label for="photoorig">URL</label>
  <input type="url" name="photoorig" placeholder="">
  <input type="submit" value="Load"  name="photoload">
  <br>
</form>

<form method="post" action="bigorder.php" name="photofile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="photoloc">Load own file</label>
  <input type="file" name="photoloc" id="photoloc">
  <input type="submit" value="Load" name="photoload2">
</form>
```

And php

```
<?php 
  $tmpname=rand().".jpg";
  if ($_POST['photoorig']) {
    $file=file_get_contents($_POST['photoorig']);
    $fp = fopen("/var/www/html/uploads/tmp/".$tmpname, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $file);
    fclose($fp);
  }
  if ($_POST['photoloc']) {
    $tmpFile = $_FILES['photoloc']['tmp_name'];
    $newFile = "/var/www/html/uploads/tmp/".$_FILES['photoloc']['name'];
    $result = move_upload_file($tmpFile, $newFile);
    echo $_FILES['photoloc']['name'];
      if ($result) {
        echo ' was uploaded<br />';
      } else {
        echo ' failed to upload<br />';
   }
?>
```

First form loads files fine, but the second one doesn't work at all. I even don't receive any error message.

What am I doing wrong? Or missing something?

Comment: The function to use is `move_uploaded_file()`, not `move_upload_file()`

Comment: Also, if nothing is outputted, maybe it's because the condition `if($_POST['photoloc'])` is never met?

Comment: @D4V1D, thank you! Changing to the right `move_uploaded_file()` helped to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code,it is working.In your code curly braces was missing in second form and isset() function should use to check posted data set or not.

```
 <?php 
       $tmpname=rand().".jpg";
      if (isset($_POST['photoload'])) {
        echo '1st';
        $file=file_get_contents($_POST['photoorig']);
        $fp = fopen("/var/www/html/uploads/tmp/".$tmpname, "w");
        fwrite($fp, $file);
        fclose($fp);
      }
      if (isset($_POST['photoload2'])) {
        echo '2nd';
        $tmpFile = $_FILES['photoloc']['tmp_name'];
        $newFile = "/var/www/html/uploads/tmp/".$_FILES['photoloc']['name'];
        $result = move_upload_file($tmpFile, $newFile);
        echo $_FILES['photoloc']['name'];
          if ($result) {
            echo ' was uploaded<br />';
             } else {
            echo ' failed to upload<br />';
                }
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: Now it works! Also i changed `move_upload_file()` to `move_uploaded_file()` as @D4V1D advised!